# SQL merge and convert two bools to string column

Tags: sql, sql-merge

I have a table with two smallint (bool) columns. I would like to merge these two columns into 1 varchar (string) column, and then delete the two smallint columns. It should be merged so that:

```
false false = "blue"
false true = "yellow"
true false = "red"
```

Eg:

```
column_1    Column_2    Column_3
0           1           "yellow"
1           0           "red"
0           0           "blue"
0           0           "blue"
```

However I don't really know where to start.
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression.

Comment: The key to problem solving is breaking the problem down. Is the part you're stuck on: 1. How do I calculate a single value from two columns? 2. How do I add a column to a table? 3. How do I update a column based on the expression I worked out in step 1? 4. How do I drop the columns once I don't need them? SQL Server doesn't care that your task is to "merge" the columns; it will just see these four steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a case statement. I have left an `ELSE` for any other scenario

```
select column1, column2,
       case 
           when column1 = 1 and column2 = 0 then 'red'
           when column1 = 0 and column2 = 1 then 'yellow'
           when column1 = 0 and column2 = 0 then 'blue'
           else 'Other'
      end as col3
from MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to create the new column with an [`ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html). So you'll need to alter your table and add a new column with the `VARCHAR` format. Then you create the data with the following [`CASE WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

```
UPDATE TableNameHere
SET column_3 = CASE
    WHEN column_1 = 0 AND column_2 = 1 THEN "yellow"
    WHEN column_1 = 1 AND column_2 = 0 THEN "red"
    WHEN column_1 = 0 AND column_2 = 0 THEN "blue"
    --You can add an ELSE if the column should not be null
  END;
```

After that, you can drop the first two columns with another `ALTER TABLE`.

Note that I inserted documentation to MySQL documentation, but this is standard SQL syntax that should be the same on SQL server.

Comment: Note that SQL Server doesn't have a proper boolean type, so you need to explicitly say `column_1 = 1` and `column_1 = 0` to compare the integer values.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your statement, thanks for that.